# React Router not switching to non-base routes

Tags: reactjs, react-router, reach-router

I'm setting up React Router in a project that was previously using Reach Router.

Before, the routes looked like this with Reach:

```
import { Router } from '@reach/router';

...

<Router>
      {anon ? <AnonHomepage /> : <Homepage />}
      <Explore path="explore/:category" />
</Router>
```

And then, switching to React Router, I have my file set up like this:

```
import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

...

<BrowserRouter>
      <Switch>
        {anon ? (
          <Route path="/" component={AnonHomepage} />
        ) : (
          <Route path="/" component={Homepage} />
        )}
        <Route
          path="/explore/:category"
          component={Explore}
        />
      </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```

But, the router keeps only showing the AnonHomepage and/or the Homepage in that `/` route, never the `/explore` (or any other) route anymore. What am I doing wrong? How can I make it use the correct components instead of always showing the base route's components?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`exact` prop](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/exact-bool) on the Route

```
import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

...

<BrowserRouter>
      <Switch>
        {anon ? (
          <Route exact path="/" component={AnonHomepage} />
        ) : (
          <Route exact path="/" component={Homepage} />
        )}
        <Route
          path="/explore/:category"
          component={Explore}
        />
      </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Comment: Thank you! This is `exact`ly what I needed!

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: you need to pass the Boolean prop `exact` to your root route, like so:

```
<Switch>
  <Route exact path='/' component={YourComponent} />
  <Route path='path/to/other/component' component={OtherComponent) />
</Switch>
```

Explanation: Checkout the documentation on the `<Switch>` component [here](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Switch).  `Switch` renders only the *first* route whose `path` prop matches the current location.  Essentially, when React Router receives a new navigation and looks for a Route to match it to, it tests the navigation path with the `Route` path as if the `Route` path were a regular expression.  Because *every* navigation path on your website includes the root path, `path='/'` will match every possible navigation.  Since the root `Route` is the first route listed, it is the first route `Switch` will test, and since that test will necessarily result in a match, `Switch` never tests the other routes, it just renders the root component.

Adding the `exact` prop to a route does what you would expect--it prevents `Switch` from detecting a match unless the path in the `Route` is *exactly* the navigation path. So '/root/other/folder' will *not* match '/' on a route whose `exact` prop is set, because '/'  is not *exactly* equal to '/root/other/folder'.